# Split up electromagnet coil, put in parallel.Why doesn't anyone do that?

Tags: electromagnetism

If the goal is to make a strong electromagnet, wouldn't it be wiser to cut the coil in different sections and then connect them to a power source in parallel?

total of 2k turns:

(+)--- <- 1k
-----(-) <-1k

turns into
(+)---(-) <- 1k
(+)---(-) <- 1k

I know that the Magnetomotive force is equal to ampere * turns. If I reduce the number of turns by half, then the resistance will also be halved, which will double the ampere resulting in the same Magnetomotive force. But what if I half the windings, but then put two of them literally next to each other as if they were one coil, wouldn't this result in a 2x Magnetomotive force? I'm not 100% sure what to think, if it's even linear or not.

For answering purpose, let's say that saturation is not a problem.

Comment: That nobody does that is not even correct. Bitter magnets are built that way, although their most important feature is the design that lets high pressure cooling water flow trough them in such a way that the enormous amount of heat they generate can be removed safely.

Comment: So instead having conductors in parallel all you need to do is to increase the cross-sectional area of the conductor.  This article describes such "swiss roll" and Bitter magnets. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DoeDdL_sWKYC&pg=PA452&lpg=PA452&dq=swiss+roll+magnets+physics&source=bl&ots=vxpYERhNqA&sig=DVGkK3dkm9kT0DMqXA_4FUz2jh0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj07qXr0ovOAhVXOMAKHap8Ak0Q6AEIPzAG#v=onepage&q=swiss%20roll%20magnets%20physics&f=false

Comment: And the force gets what? doubled? quadrupled?

Comment: And no, it's not "really" a bitter magnet, according to the information I've gathered the windings appears to be interleaved in a bitter magnet, not seperate as my lovely figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this stackexchange is awesome, I got no answer.

Answer (score 1):

So the total current supplied to your two solenoids will be 4 times larger. And that means that you are heating the supply lines, or fry your circuit breakers

Comment: And fry the magnet, too. :-)

Comment: Okay, I ask what happens to the force, instead I get a captain-obvious-answer about the current. Thanks.